# Webcomponents.js issue on IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, polyfills

I try to make a simple web component.

For browser compatibility, I use the NPM package webcomponents.js (version 0.7.23). I run my little code with Polyserve.

My code is on Github: https://github.com/olofweb/Webcomponents

- On Chrome (version 55) -> ok
- On IE (version 11) -> ko
- On Firefox (version 50.1) -> ko

Error:

https://github.com/olofweb/Webcomponents/blob/master/hello-world.html#L31

IE 11 (sorry, I don't have the english error) :
"L'objet ne gère pas la propriété ou la méthode "createShadowRoot""

Firefox 50.1 :
"TypeError: this.createShadowRoot is not a function"

Comment: [createShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/createShadowRoot) is depreciated, and likely already removed in those versions. They're not even enabled in firefox/ie as it's still an experimental technology.

Comment: @FrankerZ And what to use instead ?

Comment: Sorry, I just see your link and I found that I have to use `attachShadow()`. But I have the same error in IE and FF (Github updated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main file `index.html` you are loading the `webcomponents-lite.js` script, which doesn't include the Shadow DOM polyfill.

Instead, try to load `webcomponents.js`.

---

For Shadow DOM v1 `attachShadow()`, you should use instead the [ShadyDOM polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/shadydom). In this case you should use `webcomponents-lite.js` otherwise there will be a conflict with `createShadowRoot()` polyfill.

```
<script src="./node_modules/webcomponents.js/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<script src="shadydom.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (!Array.from) {
    Array.from = function (object) {
        'use strict';
        return [].slice.call(object);
    };
}
</script>
```

Comment: With `createShadowRoot`, your solution works. But I don't like it because this function is depreciated. I have to find a solution with the new function (`attachShadow`)...

Comment: @Olof then use th ShadyDOM polyfill

Comment: ok, I try with ShadyDOM and now it works on FF, but always not in IE11 (error on shadydom.min.js, ligne 9, colonne 3419, L'objet ne gère pas la propriété ou la méthode "from")... Github updated

Comment: it's because Array.from doesn't exist on IE11. Use a polyfill for that too. See my updated answer.