# ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom support in Edge, IE, and older browsers

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, shadow-dom

I'm using angular 7 with material. Some of my components uses ShadowDOM ViewEncapsulation and I'm getting error in IE, Edge, and some older versions of Chrome, Firefox.

here's the error description:

**Object doesn't support property or method 'attachShadow'**

also I've included some default polyfills, but still the same error occurs.

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/**
 * If the application will be indexed by Google Search, the following is required.
 * Googlebot uses a renderer based on Chrome 41.
 * https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/rendering
 **/
import 'core-js/es6/array';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 // (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

 /*
 * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 */
// (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.


/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

Comment: IE, Edge and older Firefox [don't have native implementation for ShadowDOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow#Browser_compatibility), you’ve to put another JavaScript dependency in your website by adding a script reference to `WebComponentsJs`: https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs. You can also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697490/webcomponents-js-issue-on-ie-and-firefox).

Comment: @AndrewHill by the way i saw answers of "duplicate", and it doesnt helped at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that we only need to add [ShadyDOM polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/shadydom) so that `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDOM` will be supported in IE and Edge(I don't have other older browsers so only tested in IE and Edge). I find the link of polyfill from [here](https://www.cdnpkg.com/shadydom) and I add 
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/shadydom/1.1.0/shadydom.min.js"></script>` in my `index.html`, then it works.

In my comment above, adding reference to `WebComponentsJs` only works in Edge. But adding `shadydom` polyfill works in both IE and Edge.

Comment: It removed the error `Object doesn't support property or method 'attachShadow`, however adding shadyDom created some other wonkiness with an `Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?` error. May just have to wait until Edge 76 comes out which will support Shadow Dom.

Comment: This file creates several other issues. Edge is the only reason we are not using ShadowDom.